# Get index of multiple <a> tags

Tags: javascript, html

I need the index of every `<a>`.
This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to pass it to my function

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="myAnchor">Link</a><br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor1">Link</a><br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor2">Link</a><br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor3">Link</a><br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor4">Link</a><br>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var test = this.test = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var counter = 0; counter < test.length; counter++) {
        index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(test, test[counter]);
        test[counter].onclick = runTheExample;
        console.log(index);
    }
}

function runTheExample() {
    alert();
}
```

I need an alert when an element is clicked. I think this in console output is DOM index number. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You want to get the `index` of your element in your parent `nodeList`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persist the index in html attribute and then use it in alert method. Update your js file with below code snippet -

```js
window.onload = function() {
   var test = this.test = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
   for (var counter = 0; counter < test.length; counter++){
      index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(test,test[counter]);
      test[counter].setAttribute('index',index) // add index attribute to DOM
      test[counter].onclick = runTheExample ;
      console.log(index);

   }
}

function runTheExample(index){
   alert(this.getAttribute('index')); // Use index attribute here
}
```

Comment: wow love this solution clean and simple
ps you dont need agrument for function down thnaks

Comment: @Night5talker, but you don't mind the round trip, do you? 1) Get the index, 2) Set the index (DOM scan), 3) Read the index (DOM scan) => is an overkill for a simple task. It's not just about a solution, but, about an elegant solution, which, this isn't.

Comment: @lshettyl enlight me, im still new at this, easiest thing is just say its wrong without giving "elegant solution"

Comment: @Night5talker, if you'd looked closely, there was already an [_elegant solution_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32936219/572827)

Answer (score 3):

I would try an IIFE like below.

```
window.onload = function() {
   var test = this.test = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
   for (var counter = 0; counter < test.length; counter++){
      (function (index) {
          test[index].onclick = function () {
              runTheExample(index);
          }
      }(counter));
   }
}

function runTheExample(index){
   alert(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it. All you do is use `Array.prototype.indexOf` for the list of `a` elements inside `e.target.parentNode` and search for the value of `e.target`.

`e.target` = Your `a` element.

`e.target.parentNode` = `a` parent element.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('a'), e.target);
      alert(index);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="myAnchor">Link</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor1">Link</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor2">Link</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor3">Link</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor4">Link</a>
<br>
```

If you depend on your `id` attribute then all you got to do is get all the numbers at the end of the string:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var index = e.target.id.match(/\d*$/);
      alert(index);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="myAnchor">Link</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor1">Link</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor2">Link</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor3">Link</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor4">Link</a>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your nodeList to an array and add a click `eventListener` in a `forEach` to get the index of the clicked anchor.

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    output = document.querySelector('p'),
    anchorsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(anchors);

anchorsArray.forEach(function(elem, index) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    output.innerHTML = "You have clicked the anchor with the index of " + index;
  }, false);   
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="myAnchor">Link</a><br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor1">Link</a><br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor2">Link</a><br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor3">Link</a><br>
<a href="#" id="myAnchor4">Link</a><br>

<p class="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all `<a>`:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
```

Go through each link:

```
[].forEach.call(links, function(link, index) { });
```

Add a click event to every link:

```
link.addEventListener("click", function() {});
```

Here you want to alert the index:

```
link.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(index);
});
```

Complete **JavaScript**:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

[].forEach.call(links, function(el, index) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(index);
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dL96nLup/)